# Communication between windows service and wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

My Situation:

I have a windows service "A" and a wcf service "B" which is hosted in an other windows service. In my windows service A I create a list which I then want to pass to the wcf service B. The wcf service B then edits this list and will have to pass it back.

How should I connect these two services? Do I have to reference service A in the wcf service? or do I have to make a client out of my windows service A and add a service reference?

I am thankful for any kind of help. I spend a lot of time searching on google stackoverflow and msdn but couldn't find 
something helping me.

**EDIT**

Windows Service

```
public long GetSize(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo direc = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        long size = CalculateDirectorySize(direc, true);

        return size;
    }
```

WCF Service

```
using WindowsService;

WindowsServiceMethode wsm = new WindowsServiceMethod();

public long GetWcfCheck(string path)
        {
            long size = wsm.GetSize(path);

            return size;
        }
```

ASP.Net Webapp

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            WCF.CommunicationServiceClient client = new WCF.CommunicationServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationService");
            ViewBag.s = client.GetWcfCheck(@"_somepath_").ToString();


            return View("ShowView");
        }
```

Is this a proper way of passing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I could understand from your question:

1. You have 2 Windows Services (Service1 and Service2 for simplicity)
2. Service1 hosts a WCF service
3. Service2 needs to consume a two-way method of the WCF service

If all this is correct, here are some things you should be doing:

The WCF service should be configured to connect through [NetNamedPipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding(v=vs.110).aspx), because, as explained in that article,

> NetNamedPipeBinding provides a secure and reliable binding that is optimized for on-machine communication.

Service2 needs to add a **Service Reference** to the WCF service, you can find how to do it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

Now that Service1 knows of Service2 (and Service2 has absolutely no point in knowing Service1), you have to declare your service methods to allow the two-way communication. Here's an example of an implementation I did:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Your.Namespace", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ICommunicator
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    string StartServer(string serverData);
} 

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public class CommunicatorService : ICommunicator
{
    public string StartServer(string serverData)
    {
        //example method that takes a string as input and returns another string
        return "Hello!!!!";
    }
}
```

Edit: adding client and server configuration. I must tell you, however, that since I was having multiple unrelated app.config problems, the client configuration is done through code.

Server app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.CommunicatorServiceBehavior" name="MyNamespace.CommunicatorService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" name="netNamedPipeCommunicator" contract="MyNamespace.ICommunicator">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" name="mexNamedPipeCommunicator" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/CommunicatorService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyNamespace.CommunicatorServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client's code:

```
private static ICommunicator Proxy;
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ICommunicator)))
{
   Address = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/CommunicatorService"),
   Binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding()
};
Proxy = (new DuplexChannelFactory<ICommunicator>(new InstanceContext(this), endpoint)).CreateChannel();
((IClientChannel)Proxy).Open();

public void StartServer(string serverData)
{
    string serverStartResult = Proxy.StartServer(serverData); // calls the method I showed above
}
```

Comment: Do you maybe have a link for an explanation how the app.config file looks like?

Comment: @Duck do you want to see the configuration of the server's app.config or the client's?

Comment: Both would be nice :)

Comment: And I have another question. I am new to Wcf and have some trouble understanding it. When I want to pass the return value from an method in my windows service to the wcf service how do I do it correctly? I already did it once. I referenced the windows service in the wcf service and called the method, is this the way you do it?

Comment: @Duck please see my update and let me know if you have any other question

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answer it helped me a lot :) ! I have another question let me just update my post.

Comment: @Duck, where are you hosting the WCF service? In the windows service? If so, that's correct. However, if both services are in the same machine, I strongly recommend you to use NamedPipes, otherwise, BasicHttp is fine